# Query group by column and then export multiple rows as single row

Tags: mysql, wordpress, csv, export-to-csv

Using Mysql I can run the following query

```
SELECT `meta_value` 
FROM wordpress.wp_postmeta 
WHERE post_id 
IN (SELECT post_id FROM wordpress.wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = "Tuesday" AND meta_key = "_field_93")
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/Tuesday.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY ','
```

And I currently get the following where the data in each row is currently cascaded down & grouped by `post_id` for example:

post_id = 1112345 (example not in CSV file)

```
,21
,Tuesday
,John Smith
,abc 123
```

post_id = 1112346 (example not in CSV file)

```
,qrz22
,Tuesday
,Bob Godfrey
,ABC 229986
```

What I need it to do is have each `post_id` be a line where all the rows are then CSV separated across that line. for example:

post_id = 1112345 (example not in CSV file)

```
,21 ,Tuesday ,John Smith ,abc 123
```

post_id = 1112346 (example not in CSV file)

```
,qrz22 ,Tuesday ,Bob Godfrey ,ABC 229986
```

I'm sure the answer is staring me in the face however I'm no SQL guru and I have no idea where I'm going wrong.
I've looked into the `group_concat` command but every time I try to put it into my query I just get an error.

Would really appreciate any help that anyone could give me on this, and sorry if my request doesn't make any sense, again I'm no SQL guru.

Comment: Are your values always going to be the same 4 meta_key values?

Comment: Yes the meta_key values will always be the same

Answer (score 0):

How about enumerating the field values, otherwise known as a pivot.

```
SELECT max(if(meta_key,'...',meta_value,null) as field_one,
       max(if(meta_key,'_field_93',meta_value,null) as field_two,
       max(if(meta_key,'...',meta_value,null) as field_three,
       max(if(meta_key,'...',meta_value,null) as field_four
FROM   wordpress.wp_postmeta 
WHERE  post_id 
IN (SELECT post_id
    FROM   wordpress.wp_postmeta
    WHERE  meta_value = "Tuesday"
    AND    meta_key = "_field_93")
GROUP BY post_id
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/Tuesday.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY ',';
```